# How to define a \verb-like command that can be used in table and headings?

Tags: verbatim, latex3

I want to define a `\verb`-like command, `\keyword`, for example, to make the following code work as desired. Can anybody help me?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{newverbs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\newverbcommand{\keyword}{\begingroup\color{blue}}{\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

C contains the following keywords:
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
      \hline
      \keyword|int| & int \\ \hline
      \keyword|_Thread_local| & thread storage-class specifier  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

C contains the following keywords:
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \keyword|int| & int \\ \hline
    \keyword|_Thread_local| & thread storage-class specifier  \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}

\subsection{Introduction to \keyword|_Thread_local|}

\keyword|_Thread_local|: thread storage-class specifier.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly why do you want it with that syntax when `\keyword{...}` is enough?

Comment: `\verb`-likes are usable in `tabular`.

Comment: Verbatim mode should be used only when really necessary. What special characters do you plan to need in the argument of `\keyword`?

Comment: To elaborate on egreg's comment, verbatim is hard because it changes lots of internals.  It seems that the only effect of verbatim that you're wanting is to typeset `_`, possibly have a monospace font, and change the color.  Are there other changes that you need?  Are there other special characters that you'd like to enable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using verbatim commands inside a `table` resp. `tabular` is not really a problem.

Using verbatim commands inside the argument of another command is limited, because the tokens are already build after reading the argument of the other command. So if you use an argument to the verbatim command, that is only allowed after changing the catcode, this would not work. But you can use [package `cprotect`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cprotect) as a workaround:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{newverbs}
\usepackage{cprotect}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\newverbcommand{\keyword}{\begingroup\color{blue}}{\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

C contains the following keywords:
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
      \hline
      \keyword|int| & int \\ \hline
      \keyword|_Thread_local| & thread storage-class specifier  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

C contains the following keywords:
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \keyword|int| & int \\ \hline
    \keyword|_Thread_local| & thread storage-class specifier  \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}

\cprotect\subsection{Introduction to \keyword|_Thread_local|}

\keyword|_Thread_local|: thread storage-class specifier.

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, only `xltabular` is a problem. But, because you don't use any `X`-column, I would suggest, to simply use a `longtable` (if page breaks are needed) or `tabular` instead.

If you need `xltabular` use the verbatim argument type of `\NewDocumentCommand` instead of `\newverbcommand`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xltabular}

\NewDocumentCommand{\keyword}{v}{\textcolor{blue}{\texttt{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

C contains the following keywords:
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
      \hline
      \keyword|int| & int \\ \hline
      \keyword|_Thread_local| & thread storage-class specifier  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

C contains the following keywords:
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \keyword|int| & int \\ \hline
    \keyword|_Thread_local| & thread storage-class specifier  \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}

\subsection{Introduction to \keyword|_Thread_local|}

\keyword|_Thread_local|: thread storage-class specifier.

\end{document}
```

[image: using \NewDocumentCommand also corrects the xltabular]

Note: This does not work, e.g., for `\keyword|\Thead_local|` instead of `\keyword|_Thread_local|`.